# How to add values from a list and a corresponding for loop to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a list of variables as below:

```
variables = ['positional_versatility', 'weak_foot', 'skill_moves']
```

Then I have a for loop which prints the coefficient of each variable:

```
for (v, c) in zip(variables, model.coef_):
    print("%s has coefficient %5.4f" % (v, c))
```

Which outputs:

```
positional_versatility has coefficient 0.0041
weak_foot has coefficient -0.0421
skill_moves has coefficient 0.0010
```

**My question**: how do I add these coefficient values, with their corresponding variable names, to a dataframe?

Comment: How looks DataFrame? There are 2 columns? Or one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DataFrame` constructor for 2 columns DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':variables, 'b': model.coef_})
```

Comment: awesome thank you! once I've done feature importance analysis to get the coefficients of my independent variables, I want to know how to implement them into an updated model to make it more accurate. if you're able to give any tips I'd be very grateful. thanks, Tom

Comment: @TomBomer unfirtunately I am offline, on phone only. Is possible create new question with all information, best with sime input data and expected output? I hope somobody help you with some idea. Thank you.

Comment: ok I will create a new question, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `dict` and `zip` with the DataFrame constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([dict(zip(variables, model.coef_))])
```

output:

```
   positional_versatility  weak_foot  skill_moves
0                  0.0041    -0.0421        0.001
```

or better use a `Series`:

```
s = pd.Series(coef, index=variables)
# or
# s = pd.Series(dict(zip(variables, coef)))
```

output:

```
positional_versatility    0.0041
weak_foot                -0.0421
skill_moves               0.0010
dtype: float64
```